# Maximise the earnings

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, puzzle

Imagine you have two boxes, of which both are empty. Also, let's say you have a 100 turns. In each turn, you have two options:

1. You decide to place a coin :- A box will be randomly chosen, and you have to place a coin in that box. Assume choosing any box is equally likely.
2. You decide to choose a box:- A box will be randomly chosen, and you will take all the coins from the box and add them to your earnings. Again, both boxes have equal probability of being chosen.

Devise a strategy to maximise the earnings and estimate the number of coins won.

I tried solving the question by writing an expression for the expected value of the amount of coins won but couldn't make much progress beyond that.

Comment: If the coins aren't "yours" to begin with (that is, your profit is just however many coins you hold at the end), then wouldn't the best strategy be to "place a coin" for 99 turns, and then "choose a box" on the 100th turn (in which case you'll expect to earn 49.5 coins)?

Comment: I guess we can prove that the best strategy is to first put coins at the beginning and take coins at the end (you can try to prove its optimality by swapping two actions), and then the question becomes the time that changes from putting coins to taking coins, which is much easier

Comment: @zcsttn compare that to the strategy of placing coins 98 times in a row and then choosing to pull for the final two options.  Each of the 98 coins will individually have probability $\frac{3}{4}$ of having been given to you in the end so by linearity of expectation you'd have $\frac{3}{4}\cdot 98\approx 74$ coins.  It isn't as simple as you make it out to be.

Comment: So then, following from my comment you should be able to take advantage of linearity of expectation and come up with a formula for what the expected number of coins received at the end is if you were to place coins the first $n$ turns and pull coins the remaining $100-n$ turns.  From there it is a matter of calculus to find the maximum of the expression, then find which of the neighboring integral values is highest.  To complete the problem, you should also be able to explain why this obvious strategy of only placing coins and only after do you pull is actually the best strategy.

Comment: @JMoravitz Good point.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sure, the best greedy strategy is to place 94 coins and take 6 times, which gives the expectation 2961/32

Answer (score 3):

First, if you choose to put coins before pull coins, the expectation should be improved if you swap these two actions. Therefore, the best strategy must be first putting $100-k$ coins and then pulling $k$ times.

Next, let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the number of coins in boxes, we have $X_1+X_2=100-k$. As we pull $k$ times, we have $1/2^k$ probability that getting only $X_1$, $1/2^k$ probability that getting only $X_2$, and $1-2/2^k$ probability that getting $X_1+X_2$, the expectation is hence $(1-1/2^k)(100-k)$.

Finally, we search for the best $k$ (or you can take the derivative and then try the integer nearby), and you should have $k=6$ with the maximum expectation $2961/32$.